# AngularJS ng-repeat not showing items

Tags: html, angularjs

Today I started fiddling with AngularJS for school. Almost instantly I got to a problem I cannot fix, and solutions on the internet did not help me.

I use a angular-seed project as skeleton of my project.

This results in two files in particular: the app.js and the view1.js which contains the controller I am using in my view1.html.

The idea is that I need to have an array of items that I can use globally on multiple views, so not necessarily only on view 1.

I made a controllers.js with the following content:

```
var todoAppControllers = angular.module('CarControllers', []);



todoAppControllers.controller('CarListController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.cars = [
      {merk:'volkswagen', model : 'Up'},
      {merk:'volkswagen', model : 'Golf'}
      ];

  }]);
```

My html looks like this on the main index.html (I've ommitted some irrelevant code):

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="carApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('carApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'carApp.view1',
  'CarControllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

And finally the page where I want to show my list of cars. Not that this is a partialview:

```
<p>Cars:</p>
<ul ng-controller="CarListController">
    <li ng-repeat"car in cars">{{car.merk}} model: {{car.model}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I run npm and go to the application, I only see one bulletpoint (list item) with only model: (so no merk which is brand in Dutch nor the car.model).

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at your browser console for errors. Post a complete example in a plunkr, because many parts are missing, and we have no idea of the error.

Comment: That's the funny part: I get 0 error codes!

Comment: create a fiddle , we will do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
<li ng-repeat"car in cars">
```

You're missing an equal symbol:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
```

Comment: How ridiculous that I did not see that.. Tunnelvision, I guess!